# How to plot a bar plot/histogram with labels of a variable from a dictonary?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, statistics, bar-chart

[Sample graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccNu9.png)
I have a dataframe which consists of many columns of categorical variables. Each column has values which are categorical (For eg, A, B, C, D, etc where they represent a particular value). Now, I need to plot a bar plot or a histogram where I can read out the corresponding values in the columns based on what they mean.
For eg. there is a column called 'food' which contains thousands of values such as a,b,c,d means apple, banana, couscous and dragon respectively. So I need the x-axis of the barplot to read from a dictonary the corresponding values. In other words, the x-axis should read apple instead of a and banana instead of 'b'. Any suggestions?

Comment: you should provide a minimal reproducible dataset as input and a mockup of the expected graph

Comment: Added a picture for reference. The picture on the right is what I want my plot to look like. The corresponding values need to be stored in a dictonary I suppose